# Two Fields at the same table row

Tags: xpages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81pDq.png)How to remove this line? this 2 fiels are in the table. 
Table is in a Panel and panel is in a table row.

When i put 2 field into same table row. one field stays under the first field. I just want 2 fields to stand side by side(abreast)

Here is the simple code that maybe you can help me to show both 2 field abreast by adding a CSS code. I do not know which CSS property will help me

```
<xp:table style="width:646.0px">
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText2"></xp:inputText>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText3"></xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText4"></xp:inputText>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText5"></xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>
```

Comment: More details are needed: please add code that shows what you have done.

Comment: I guess, this can be done with css formatting, but as this question is written noone kann know

Comment: <xp:table style="width:646.0px">
  <xp:tr>
   <xp:td>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText2"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText3"></xp:inputText></xp:td>
   <xp:td>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText4"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText5"></xp:inputText></xp:td>
  </xp:tr>
  <xp:tr>
   <xp:td></xp:td>
   <xp:td></xp:td>
  </xp:tr>
 </xp:table>

Comment: here is the simple code that maybe you can help me to show both 2 field abreast by adding a CSS code.  I do not know which CSS property will help me...:(

Comment: Curious why someone down-voted this. Was it because the code wasn't in there originally?

Comment: I downvoted because there was no code and it was not clear at all, what the question was. Now with the information from the comments the question is clear, so I pulled back my downvote (although the OP should have edited that information into the post himself)

Comment: I uploaded 2 pictures. One of them is How It looks like.

Comment: Seconed one is what i want to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Table is the element of choice to have items row up, but not as you use it in your example. if you change the code like that, then you don't need to use css at all:

```
<xp:table style="width:646.0px">
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText2"></xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText3"></xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText4"></xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText5"></xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>
```

If this is not possible (for whatever reason), then you can change the "display"- style of your inputText- Elements. Although your example alone does not show the described behaviour (your example code does show inline in my tests) you could change the code like this:

```
<xp:table style="width:646.0px">
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText2" style="display: inline"></xp:inputText>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText3"></xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText4" style="display: inline"></xp:inputText>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText5"></xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. :( is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you really KNOW what the difference between row and cell is? Please: post your ORIGINAL code in your question and show, what you tried... i gave you two examples. To say "I tried and it did not work" is not helpfull at all

Comment: When i wrote row. I meant cell.. I just used the wrong word.. Sorry.  I really do not  have experience on CSS and which css property link you mentioned above (display:inline, display:inline-block etc.. have to be used. Orjiginal code is the same above. 
does the style="display:inline" CSS property in the example you gave it before has to work? 
thanks for you help... by the way I am new one here and I cannot paste all the codes and picture I would like to show. :(